# NoClassDefFoundError in building gradle project

Tags: gradle, gradlew

So, it really consumed a lot of my time. I am trying to build a project (using gradle) that is using these jar
'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2'
'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.1'

Content of my `build.gradle` (staging plugin):

```groovy
apply plugin:'groovy'
apply plugin:'idea'
apply plugin:'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = "1.7"

def nexusUrl = "http://nexus/nexus/content/groups/artifacts"

project.ext.set("nexusUsername", nexusUsername)

dependencies{
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-1.8'

      compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2@jar'
      compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.0.1'
      //compile 'maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:1.2@plugin'
}

jar {
  baseName=projectName
}
```

http-builder jar uses cobertura-plugin 1.3.plugin which is not available. To avoid transitive dependency, I've used `http-builder:0.7.2@jar`.

httpclient jar have `DefaultHttpClient` class.

Then, I am using this project in another project. Now, I am getting error in building this project

Content of `build.gradle` in project ABC:

```groovy
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.abc.gradle.plugins:staging-plugin:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT@jar'
    }
}
```

I have to use @jar because if I don't use, http-builder will try to download cobertura:1.3.plugin which is not available (but I think this is not an issue).
But when I run this project, it gives NoClassDefFoundError error.

Command to run this proct : ./gradlew createStagingRepository

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient

Content of httpclient-4.5.2.jar

```
jar tvf httpclient-4.5.2.jar  | grep "DefaultHttpClient"
  2647 Sun Feb 21 17:04:42 PST 2016 org/apache/http/impl/client/SystemDefaultHttpClient.class
  3537 Sun Feb 21 17:04:42 PST 2016 org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.class
  8123 Sun Feb 21 17:04:42 PST 2016 org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.class
```

Comment: You've provided too little information. Share your `build.gradle` file along with project structure and usage scenario.

Comment: I've updated the content